# YII: Stop YII from clearing session on logout?

Tags: session, yii

I currently store a user's cart content in session. The problem is, I don't want this information, which is stored at:

```
YII::app()->session['cart']
```

.. to be cleared when the user logs out. And for various reasons, I also don't want to store it in the database.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Yii::app()->user->logout(false)`. It will only remove the authentication related information from session and keep the other data there intact.

Answer (score 0):

You must save it in some way. But You have alternative way to save is.

[COOKIES][ http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpCookie], it save in the client site. but it can't retrieve it if the use clean the cookies.

I **my opinion**, Save it in the DB. Create table for sessions, and use [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to convert the _SESSION to string, and when the user login read the session from DB and use [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Comment: This ultimately fixed my problem --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480229/yii-session-id-changes-when-i-login-but-not-when-i-logout/15482359#15482359