# Preserve Session on Logout and Login

Tags: session, yii

I print out the session ID like this:

```
<?php print YII::app()->session->sessionID; ?>
```

When I `log-in` and check my `ID`, it is something like: `huh09vuo33scdlkmfuc8651t12`, for example. If I log out and check again, my ID remains the same. However, if I then log back in again, the session ID changes!

**My problem** is that I have information in my session that I need to store in a cookie and reload after login. How can I uniquely establish that the user logged in is the correct user if his session ID changes?

Comment: Did you really check the session ID **after logout** (or in the next request), because CWebUser::logout($destroySession=true)` destroys the session by default.

Comment: I checked and it doesn't even with destroySession = true. Maybe there's more wrong with my sessions than I thought. Investigating.

Comment: Don't ask me how, but setting $destroySession to false now keeps my session intact whether I log in or out. All I changed was: Yii::app()->user->logout(); --> to --> Yii::app()->user->logout(false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont ask me how, but this fixed my problem:

I changed:

```
Yii::app()->user->logout();
```

to

```
Yii::app()->user->logout(false);
```

Maybe it will help someone else, or at least steer them in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

The component `Yii::app()->user` is a `CWebUser` instance, and [`CWebUser::logout(boolean $destroySession=true)`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#logout-detail) documentation states:

> **$destroySession** (*boolean*) whether to destroy the whole session. **Defaults to true**. If false, then clearStates will be called, which removes only the data stored via setState.

Actually, `Yii::app()->user->logout(true)` destroys the session, meaning that all the session information *cannot be recovered*, and it uses PHP's [`session unset`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-unset.php) and [`session destroy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) to unset all the session information and destroy the session ID information on the server respectively. but `Yii::app()->user->logout(false)` **does not destroy the raw session information or unset the session ID**, it only clears the session states, which is the information that Yii actually uses.. You could classify this as a "soft logout", since the raw session information is kept associated with the session and only the states are disassociated from the session ID, but the session ID remains untouched..